# What can I do with de-listed stock?

Tags: stocks, united-kingdom

You had [a question regarding UK stock in the Perform Group in October 2014](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/39165/what-will-happen-to-my-shares-if-company-delisted).

I am in the unenviable position of owning the same stock but did not receive any communication or information regarding the selling and take over by Access Industries of these holdings, until it was too late and the offer to buy the shares had expired.

The company has now been de-listed and my shares are worthless.
I have tried to get some explanation as to why I had not been notified but between the broker and their agents they just say they sent the notices. Apparently there were two letters and an e-mail, I failed to get any of them. I also asked the Financial Ombudsman for help but they stated that the broker is not at fault.

Comment: Talk to a lawyer and sue for negligence?

Comment: I tried through the Financial Ombudsman but they say the Brokers (A well known bank) have my correct address and say they sent them so the Brokers are not at fault.